# PHP MYSQL query WHERE statement - Returns also rows where the condition is not met

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to query the mysql database with the following statement:

```
SELECT form_data.*, forms.orderId, forms.eType 
FROM form_data 
LEFT JOIN forms ON form_data.fieldId = forms.id 
WHERE form_data.submitId='somehashedid' 
ORDER BY forms.orderId ASC
```

If I use this statement within phpmyadmin the output returns only rows containing the submitId which is handed over. Which is exactly what I want.

But trying to use the same query in php returns also rows not containing the correct submitId

```
function getReportDetails($reportId) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT form_data.*, forms.orderId, forms.eType FROM form_data LEFT JOIN forms ON form_data.fieldId = forms.id WHERE form_data.submitId=? ORDER BY forms.orderId ASC");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $reportId);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

// $_REQUEST['id'] is checked not to by empty
$data = $dao->getReportDetails($_REQUEST['id']);

// $data is checked to have an array of results
```

submitId is a **varchar(35) utf8_general_ci**

submitIds look like this **f89cf0bc3660424b017f9bfe0d8c0252**

My workaround for now is to check in my loop again if the db id matches the requested id and limit the output of only intended information. But why do I get wrong results?

If you do also have other improvements to my code please let me know.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("i", $reportId);` -- `i` is for integer, you want `s` for string.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters

Comment: Is $reportId an int?  What about when you use `intval($reportId)` ?

Comment: Please get into the habit of using `s` for everything even for integers. Use `i` only when `s` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because submitId is a varchar, you should use character 's' instead of 'i' for bind_param method(character 's' uses for bind string data type or varchar while 'i' uses for integers)
so try something like below..

```
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $reportId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! Of course. I did not see it. Copy pasted parts from a different function and did not notice that this id is not an INT as the other ids I was using before.